# Show that $|f(x)| \leq 2 \pi^2/9$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The problem is stated as:

> Show that $|f(x)| \leq 2 \pi^2/9$ for $ |x| \leq \pi/3$ where $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{cos(t)}dt$

**Solution**:

So, first of all, I try to form a Maclaurin expression around $x = 0$. Without digging into the calculations too deep, I get the following:

$f(0) = 0 \\ f'(0) = 0 \\ f''(0) = 1$

For $f^{(3)}(\theta x) = \dfrac{2\sin\left(\theta x\right)\left(\theta x\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(\theta x\right)\right)}{\cos^3\left(\theta x\right)}+\dfrac{\theta x}{\cos\left(\theta x\right)}$

Where $\theta \in (0,1)$.

Therefore, we have that our Maclaurin expansion can be written in the following form: $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} +f^{(3)}(\theta x) = \dfrac{2\sin\left(\theta x\right)\left(\theta x\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(\theta x\right)\right)}{\cos^3\left(\theta x\right)}+\dfrac{\theta x}{\cos\left(\theta x\right)}$$

Taking the absolute value of both sides, and applying the triangle ineqality, we get:

$|f(x)| \leq \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!}|\dfrac{2\sin\left(\theta x\right)\left(\theta x\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(\theta x\right)\right)}{\cos^3\left(\theta x\right)}| + |\dfrac{\theta x}{\cos\left(\theta x\right)}|$

Now, we notice that we have:

$ 1/2 \leq |\cos(\theta x)| \leq 1 \\ 0 \leq |\sin(\theta x)| \leq \sqrt{3}/2 \\ 0 \leq |\theta x |\leq \pi/3$

for $|x| \leq \pi/3$

Applying these to our inequality above, we have:

$|f(x)| \leq \pi^2/18 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{\sqrt{3}/2(\pi/3 *\sqrt{3}/2 + 1)}{1/8}+\frac{\pi/3}{1/2}$

However, when I calculate the RHS, I get a much bigger number than $2\pi^2 / 9$. How can I proceed from this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler way:

For $|x| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}, \cos x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{\cos x} \leq 2$

So, $ \displaystyle |f(x)| = \left|\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{cos(t)} ~ dt \right| \leq \int_{0}^{|x|} 2t ~ dt = x^2$.

As $ \displaystyle |x| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}, |f(x)| \leq \frac{\pi^2}{9} \leq \frac{2\pi^2}{9}$

Comment: Thank you. That's certainly easier :)

Comment: @Tanamas Glad I could help :)